# Find a selection of text but not if part of other text

Tags: vba, ms-word

I am trying to find a selection of text in a Word document and then lock the content control.

I have one search text 'Our Ref:' and another 'Your Ref:'.

When the second sub searches for 'Our Ref:' it also highlights 'Your Ref:'.

Screenshot of search result for 'our ref:'
[image]

I tried to add `.MatchPrefix` which works within the advanced find in Word, but not in the macro.

Is there a way to either skip the first result or narrow the search?

```vb
Private Sub LockOurRef()

With Selection.find
    .Text = "Our Ref:"
    .MatchWholeWord = True
    .Forward = True

    .Execute

    Selection.Range.ContentControls.Add (wdContentControlGroup)
    Selection.ParentContentControl.LockContentControl = True
    
End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Uhm, your macro is locking, not unlocking the content control and setting the Group control for the content control, which does not seem to make any sense. I would suggest posting a link to a sample document so that those trying to assist you do not have to try to recreate your problem. Here is my Article on how to do that: https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_word-mso_win10-mso_365hp/why-a-sample-file-is-important-for-troubleshooting/9441ae3c-1e92-41c6-9a1f-5b377b08e5a5?tm=1619027698258

Comment: Thanks, that should have said 'Lock' not 'Unlock' just updated.

Comment: Add `.MatchCase = True` which will distinguish between “Our Ref” and “Your Ref”